# Simulate an on paste event for testing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jestjs

I have written an on paste event for HTML text area as follows.

```html
<input type="text" onpaste="myFunction()" value="Paste something in here">
```

I want to write a test case for the paste event in Jest. How can I simulate an on paste event in Jest?

Comment: What's the code you're trying to test? Where's your attempt to test it? Please give a [mre].

Comment: <input type="text" onpaste="myFunction()" value="Paste something in here">.   The thing is i want to write a test for the above onpaste event in JEST .

Comment: [Edit] the question.

Comment: What are you using to render the component in your tests? Did you try using it to simulate a paste? What happened? Also note this is just an HTML snippet, not a [mre].

Comment: And it is input type of text not a text area.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please give me an example of a test case for any event triggered from an html text input in JEST ? like onupdate,onchange ...

Comment: Again, what's rendering it? Read the docs for Enzyme, Testing Library etc. to see setup and examples.